# Can SustainSys.Saml2 sign individual assertions when generating SamlResponses?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, sustainsys-saml2

I'm using SustainSys.Saml2 to generate SAMLResponses within an app that, internally within my organization, acts as an IdP.

The library is fully capable of signing the entire response; that works just fine.

I have a new SP over which I have no control that absolutely requires assertions to be signed. However, I can find no way to cause this to happen within the library. When I call the Saml2Response constructor and then bind it to a Post binding, the entire response is signed, but I can find no way to sign the individual assertions. I have consulted the docs, the questions and answers here, and have browsed the code quite extensively, but can find no evidence that this quite commonplace SAML usage pattern is supported.

Has anyone succeeded in getting this to work?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is currently no support for signed assertions.

The IDP functionality has never been the focus of the library, it's mostly stuff added that was needed to create the stub idp.